# Passing an int to a param of type ?float results in a PhpStorm warning

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7, type-declaration, phpstorm-2017.2

If I have `strict_types` on, and I pass in an `int` to a function that's set to accept `?float` as the param type, PhpStorm puts a warning, but the code still executes fine. Interestingly, PhpStorm doesn't put a warning if the param type is just `float` (without the `?`).

For example:

```
<?
declare(strict_types=1);

function strictTypesTest (?float $float) {
    echo $float;
}

strictTypesTest(42);
```

The last line (`strictTypesTest(42);`) has a red underline and a warning saying `Parameter is expected to be 'float|null', 'int' given`:

[image: Parameter is expected to be 'float|null', 'int' given]

The code executes fine, because on the [PHP docs on strict types](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict), there's one exception to the strict types rule:

> The only exception to this rule is that an integer may be given to a function expecting a float.

If I only put `float` as the param type (instead of `?float`), then PhpStorm doesn't put a warning.

Why is the warning only triggering when I add the `?`

Comment: Is your language version set to php 7.1 in phpstorm?

Comment: @ChristianElowsky Yep, "PHP language level: 7.1 (const visibility, nullables, multiple exceptions)" I did say that it worked without the `?` Do you get the warning if you try it on your PhpStorm?

Comment: will `strictTypestest(42.0);` do the trick?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It would, but my question wasn't how to overcome the error, it was why it was happening.

Comment: yes, but if `42.0` works and `42` not, then it indicates bug in the inspection as PHP will not complain seeing `42`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, I've filed it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38446

Comment: Thanks @EugeneMorozov, am I supposed to file bugs on YouTrack rather than Stack Overflow? Also, please let me know when it's fixed :)

Comment: @David *"am I supposed to file bugs on YouTrack rather than Stack Overflow"* Is StackOverflow is a place where you report bugs ... or a place where you only ask "is this a bug or am I doing something wrong perhaps"? *"Also, please let me know when it's fixed :)"* Watch that ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.